How do I check the existence of an S3 resource in a specific bucket?
I have been running a prototype of my project that uses this code to check if a given resource exists at a particular path, where the user has access to a single bucket:
func checkExistence(key: String) async -> Bool {
        print("checking Existence of \(key)")

        let bucketName = "nameofmybucket"
        do {
            
            var rslt = try await Amplify.Storage.getURL(
                key: key.lowercased(),
                options: .init(
                    pluginOptions: AWSStorageGetURLOptions(
                        validateObjectExistence: true
                    )
                )
            )
            return true
        } catch {
            print("not found \(key)")
            return false
        }
    }

However, this doesn't actually do anything with the bucket, and now I'm trying to adapt this to a multiple-bucket use case. How can I make this more general, to accept the string name of a given bucket as well as checking the path?
I could mention that I've been trying a variety of AI answers that suggest that this method exists:
let result = try await Amplify.Storage.getURL(key: objectKey, options: StorageGetURLRequest.Options(bucket: bucketName))

However, I'm not sure how I can make this work, since it wants the bucket: parameter as a StorageBucket(), and for whatever reason I can't find a way to generate that object from a string input, so I can't test it...
